# Matlab: How can I split my data matrix into two random subsets of column vectors while keeping the label information?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, label, sample

I have a data matrix X (60x208) and a matrix of labels Y (1x208). I want to split my data matrix X into two random subsets of column vectors: training (which will be 70% of the data) and testing (which will be 30% of the data), but I need to still be able to identify which label from Y corresponds to each column vector. I couldn't find any function to do this, any ideas?

EDIT: Thought I should add, there are only two labels in Y: 1 and 2 (not sure if this makes a difference)

Comment: What do those `1` and `2` in `Y` signify?

Comment: Just different labels. The idea is to plot them with different colours, ie. all the 1's being red and 2's being blue.

Comment: @Divakar - This is most likely a machine learning problem where you have training data with a classification label assigned to each data point.  This is a supervised algorithm where you provide a data point and the system should classify that data point to belong to that particular label.  Training data is used to train the system in order to ensure that the data gets classified to the corresponding labels.  The test set is used to gauge the accuracy, to see if the trained system can classify the data accurately based on inputs it has never seen before.... hence a test set.

Comment: @rayryeng - That's exactly it, thanks for all the help!

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for taking time to share info on those!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's pretty easy to do.  Use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to generate a random permutation of indices from `1` up to as many points as you have... which is 208 in your case.

Once you generate this sequence, simply use this and subset into your `X` and `Y` to extract the training and test data and labels.  As such, do something like this:

```
num_points = size(X,2);
split_point = round(num_points*0.7);
seq = randperm(num_points);
X_train = X(:,seq(1:split_point));
Y_train = Y(seq(1:split_point));
X_test = X(:,seq(split_point+1:end));
Y_test = Y(seq(split_point+1:end));
```

The `split_point` determines how many points we need to place into our training set, and we will need to round it in case this calculation yields any decimal points.  I also didn't hard code 208 in there because your data set might grow and so this will work with any size data set you choose.  `X_train` and `Y_train` will contain your data and labels for your training set while `X_test` and `Y_test` will contain your data and labels for your test set.

As such, the first column of `X_train` is your data point for the first element of your training set, with the first element of `Y_train` serving as the label for that particular point... and so on and so forth!

Comment: I was thinking on the same lines!+1

Comment: @Divakar - Thanks :)  Sorry I beat you to it though!