# split data set (matrix) into random data sets- matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, dataset, random

So I have a **matrix A** which is **506x13**. I would like to have random slip of it into **two sets 1/3 and 2/3**. Problem is that each of 13 columns is a specific category.

*Is there a simple way of splitting A matrix (data set) in matlab?*

This question could be closely linked with this one: [Matlab: How can I split my data matrix into two random subsets of column vectors while keeping the label information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662123/matlab-how-can-i-split-my-data-matrix-into-two-random-subsets-of-column-vectors)

However, I still can't see the way of doing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does that question not help you? Everything is row-based in the accepted answer, and you only need to change the `splitpoint` to multiply with 2/3 instead of 0.7. Using that on 13 columns doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: The linked answer is **exactly** how you should solve it.  I don't understand how it doesn't help in your situation. @Adriaan is correct in that you simply need to change 0.7 to 2/3.  Read the question and answer carefully... and try it again.  The explanation given in the accepted answer is exactly what you need.

Comment: of course... thanks. I though it will be something similar or even the same. Nevertheless thanks for clear comments

Comment: another possibility is to use `crossvalind`.